# Вычисление суммы первых k чисел последовательности

Tags: c, рекурсия, числовые-последовательности

Вычисление суммы первых k чисел последовательности a[0] = 1, a[k] = k*a[k-1] +1/k ( k = 1, 2, ... ).

В чем проблема, почему не работает ни одна, ни другая функция?(одна без рекурсии , другая с рекурсией) (специально поменяла все типы на float , т.к. думала, что проблема в этом, но и это не помогло).

**UPD** : Осталась проблема с рекурсивной функцией ...В чем ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float m(float n){
    float k=1;
    float sum=k;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<n;i++){
        k = (i*k+1.0/i);
        sum = sum+k;
    }
    return sum;
}

float Fn(float n)
{   
   if (n==0) {
   return 1;}
   
   return ((n*Fn(n-1)+1.0/n)+Fn(n-1));
  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float k;
printf("input k : ");
scanf("%f",&k);
printf("res %f \n",Fn(k));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как понять "_не работает ни одна, ни другая функция_"? Ошибка вылетает? Или возвращает не то, что вы ожидали? Тогда приведите пример входных данных, данные которые возвращают ваши функции и то, что вы ожидали увидеть.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков просто вылетает окно о прекращении работы программы.
и "..return value 3221225477"

Comment: `k = (i * k + 1.0 / i)` первая же итерация это деления на 0. Или промежуток цикла измените или `i + 1` вместо `i` используйте.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков действительно, спасибо, не заметила..Теперь всё верно считает, но в функции с рекурсией где-то ошибка, потому что не то число выводит...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно читаете числа и пишете. Типу **float** нужно ставить `%f` вместо `%d` или `%s`.

```
scanf("%f",&k);

printf("res %f \n",m(k));
```

Из-за комментария Павел Ериков нужно исправить цикл в функции `m` :

```
for (i=1; i<=n;i++){
```

В рекурсивной функции вы считаете что `Fn` - это сумма, а в задаче должен быть предыдущий элемент.

return ((n* **Fn(n-1)** +1.0/n)+Fn(n-1));

Можно сделать **две** рекурсивные функции. Одна вычисляет сумму, другая элементы последовательности.

```
float An(float n)
{   
   if (n <= 0) 
     return 1;
   return ((n*An(n-1)+1.0/n));
  }

float Sn(float n) {
  if(n <= 0)
    return 1.0;
  return Sn(n-1)+An(n); }
```

Comment: спасибо исправила.Осталась проблема с рекурсивной функцией..

Comment: @LusindaBabaika проблема в рекурсии в том, что вы не считаете нигде сумму, вы только находите последнее слагаемое. Все что пришло в голову (не очень красивое решение как по мне) это вторым параметром передавать указатель на сумму и внутри `Fn` перед `return` добавлять слагаемое к сумме (или 1 если n == 0),  а потом его возвращать

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вы бы могли это записать , пожалуйста?Я уже поняла, что я считаю только один эл-т последовательности, поэтому решила просто возвращать этот эл-т.И уже с помощью цикла в мэйне осуществить подсчет суммы.Но на ваш вариант хотелось бы посмотреть.

Comment: @LusindaBabaika код считай 1 в 1, как я и написал словами. Вот  [пример](https://ideone.com/owWAf7)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо большое, но вот почему-то на единицу больше результат возвращается, чем нужно.

Comment: По буквам внимательно всё пересмотрите.

Comment: @AlexGlebe посмотрела.Чтобы выводился нужный результат я там в Sn поменяла возвращаемое значение при n = 0 на ноль, вместо единицы.И тогда всё хорошо.Спасибо
` float Sn(float n) {
  if(n == 0)
    return 0;
  return Sn(n-1)+An(n-1); } `

Comment: @ПавелЕриков спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Приведу все таки в качестве примера, мой вариант рекурсивной функции:

```
float Fn(float n, float* sum)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        *sum += 1;
        return 1;
    }
    float tmp = ((n * Fn(n - 1, sum) + 1.0 / n));
    *sum += tmp;
    return tmp;
}
```

Он немного эффективней чем вариант, AlexGlebe, потому-что расчет каждого слагаемого происходит лишь 1 раз.

Для этой функции можно сделать функцию обертку:

```
float Fn(float n) {
    float sum = 0;
    Fn(n, &sum);
    return sum;
}
```